# .net web app displays differently after adding search column

Tags: .net, sorting

Trying to get columns to sort.  In my index.cshtml, I changed this:

```
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
    </th>
```

to this:

```
    <th>
        <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["DateSortParm"]">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)</a>
    </th>
```

When I run it in Visual Studio it displays fine, centered, etc.  When I deploy to IIS, the fonts are tiny, and everything is left justified.  Before I made the change, it displayed correctly on IIS as well.  I'm assuming it is tucking it into a frame or something.  Is there a better way to add sortable columns?

Answer (score 0):

NVM.  It is apparently something else.